# Check if third-party cookies are enabled, page render in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, session-cookies, same-origin-policy

I need to check if cookies from an external domain are enabled, the page from the external domain is rendered in an iframe on my domain, I was wondering if it is possible to perform this check using only javascript, as I found some models using PHP, but I don't have CORS access!

Comment: Afaik, javascript doesn't have a way to know about the existance of third party cookies.  From a security standpoint, there is no reason for one site to know about the cookies of another site.

Comment: check if the cookie is enabled to check if the iframe session falls

Comment: Again, from a security standpoint, that is unnecessary information for one website to know about another, that may not be related at all.  For your use case, they may be related.  But as a general standard for the web as a whole, which browsers are written for, they cannot make that assumption.

Comment: my iframe renders a page on which I authenticate, would there be any way for me to check if this authentication expires? or some way to check the session in the iframe without having cors problems?